# Apache webserver regex for filematch

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Why is it what when I put the following into my `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "*\.html$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised access only"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require user profile
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</FilesMatch>
```

It causes a 500 internal server error? Whereas if I use

```
<FilesMatch ".html$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised access only"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require user profile
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</FilesMatch>
```

It's ok and proceeds accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.*` to match anything before `\.html`

`<FilesMatch ".*\.html$">`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed to do

Comment: To clarify, `*` means nothing in that expression, unless prepended with a period (`.`). So, using `.*` and omiting it is the exact same thing.